# Good implementation approach for Layered application with 3-tier architecture?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, 3-tier, layered

I am developing an application using MVC3 and Entity Framework. Its a three layered approach with Presentation Layer hosted in Web Server and Business Layer and Data Access Layer in Application Server. We are not exposing the Object Context to Presentation Layer or Business Layer. Object Context is wrapped in Data Access Layer only and exposing data access and data persistence as functionalities as Data Access Layer methods(ie data access logic is separated and implemented in Data Access Layer only). Business Layer is calling data access layer methods and returns data to Presentation Layer.

My concern is most of the Business Layer Methods are for just to access the data and it is just forwarding the call to Data Access Layer without any operation. So we are repeating the code in both layers. Do we have any other better approach to avoid this duplication.

Is it a good practise to implement the data access logic in the business layer in Layered approach?

Can someone suggest a good implementation approach for Layered application with 3-tier architecture?

Answer (score 2):

If you find yourself that all that your business layer is doing is simply delegating the calls to the data access layer then this is a strong indication that this business layer is probably not necessary for your application as it brings no additional value. You can get rid of it and have the controllers talk directly to the data access layer (via an abstraction of course) - that's what most of the tutorials out there show with the EF data context.

In simple applications that are consisting mainly of CRUD actions, a business layer might not be necessary. As your application grows in complexity you might decide to introduce it later, but don't do too many abstractions from the beginning especially if those abstractions don't bring you any additional value.

Answer (score 2):

As previously mentioned there is no "right" way to set things up. I have found a few things over the years that help me decide which approach to take.

**Two-Tiered**

If your shop is stored procedure heavy with a lot of database programmers and tends to put business logic in the database then go with a two-tiered approach. In this situation you will find that your business layer is generally just calling the data layer. Also, If your code base and pages tend to be small and you never repeat functionality then go with a two tiered approach. You will save a lot of time.

**Three-Tiered**

If your shop likes to have a lot of business logic in code and that logic is repeated everywhere then go with three-tiered. Even if you notice a lot of your business layer just calling the data layer you will find over time when you add functionality that it is a whole lot easier to just add code to the business layer. Also, If you have a large code base with a ton of pages with a lot of repeated logic then I would definitely go with this approach.

I have found a mixture of both in our enterprise level application at my work. The problematic areas are the ones where dynamic sql (gag) was used and business logic was repeated over and over. I'm finding as I refactor I pull this code into a 3-tiered architecture and save myself a ton of time in the future because I can just reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its necessarily bad to duplicate the code for logical separation. Time will come when this will pay off. Say you will replace SQL server by Oracle. Or Microsoft will come up with Linq 2.0 and some implementations will change. You will be thanking yourself for having it separate, while those who called database right from the business layer will have to do modifications in both places - DAL and BLL.
For what its worth. But again, there's no right answer, up to utility, usability, convenience, and most importantly having it matching its purpose.

Hope this is of help.

Comment: Was it of any help to you please?